# Como usar a negação no Contains c# com LINQ?

Tags: c#, lista, linq, join

Preciso de ajuda, estou iniciando em desenvolvimento, a `eclistIds` me retorna dois ids, e se eu não usar a negação ( ! ) ele me retorna o id que eu não quero, quando uso a negação para retornar o outro id, de acordo com o `leftjoin`, ocorre erro

Meus ids são decimal

```cs
List<ExtraModel> add= (from fpp in ADD
join fpc in FPC                                                                          
   on new { fpp.fpId, fpp.etId }                                                                             
   equals new { fpc.fpId, fpc.etId }
join ec in EP on fpc.ecId equals ec.ecId
join fpcp in FPCP                                                                            
   on new { fpp.fppId, fpc.ecId }                                                                            
   equals new { fpcp.fppId, fpcp.ecId } into x
from d in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
where fpp.fpId == FPId                                                                           
      && fplistIds.Contains(fpp.fpId)                                                                            
      && etlistIds.Contains(fpp.etId)                                                                
      && !eclistIds.Contains(d.ecId)
select new ExtraModel {
fppId = d.fppId,
ecId = d.ecId }).ToList();
```

O erro que aparece é o seguinte:

```
The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.
```

SOLUÇÃO!

```
var fpcpAdd = (from fpp in FPP
join fpc in FPC 
    on new { fpp.fpId, fpp.etId } 
    equals new { fpc.fpId, fpc.etId }
join fpcp in FPCP 
    on new { fpp.fppId, fpc.ecId } 
    equals new { fpcp.fppId, fpcp.ecId } into x
from d in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
where fpp.fpId == fpId 
    && fpIds.Contains(fpp.fpId)
    && etIds.Contains(fpp.etId)
    && ecIds.Contains(fpc.ecId)
    && fpp.fppId != d.fppId
select new {
    fpp.fppId,
    fpc.ecId }).ToList();
```

OBRIGADO A TODOS!

Comment: Esse problema, creio que não seja no contains, e sim de conversão.

Comment: De acordo com o erro, o problema está na conversão de um valor null em Decimal.

Comment: Terás valores decimal a null no retorno da query devias colocar na tua classe ExtraModel os campos fppId e ecid como Decimal?

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado, mas como resolvo isso?

Comment: Ricardo não posso alterar o extraModel pois é um sistema grande e acarreta diversos erros .... A solução teria que ser no linq

Answer (score 3):

Faça um método que faça a conversão do valor e se este for nulo, retorne 0 ou -1, por exemplo.

```
public static decimal TratarDecimal(object valor)
{
    decimal result;
    if(decimal.TryParse(Convert.ToString(valor), out result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

No `Linq` verifique se dessa forma funcionará, supondo o método esteja dentro de uma classe chamada `Helper`.

```
List<ExtraModel> add= (from fpp in ADD
join fpc in FPC                                                                          
   on new { fpp.fpId, fpp.etId }                                                                             
   equals new { fpc.fpId, fpc.etId }
join ec in EP on fpc.ecId equals ec.ecId
join fpcp in FPCP                                                                            
   on new { fpp.fppId, fpc.ecId }                                                                            
   equals new { fpcp.fppId, fpcp.ecId } into x
from d in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
where fpp.fpId == FPId                                                                           
      && fplistIds.Contains(fpp.fpId)                                                                            
      && etlistIds.Contains(fpp.etId)                                                                
      && !eclistIds.Contains(d.ecId)
select new ExtraModel {
fppId = Helper.TratarDecimal(d.fppId),
ecId = Helper.TratarDecimal(d.ecId) }).ToList();
```

Talvez o `ToList()` precise ser chamado antes do `select`, caso ocorra erro me avisa que faço um ajuste aqui.